# External script not loading on mobile: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am seeing an error when loading a library JS script (Paddle Payments) from a CDN on mobile devices:

```
paddle.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

What is weird is that the same code loads and works as expected on any desktop browser, but fails to load on any mobile device.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/m0p8guta/1/). To get the actual error you can either open it on a mobile phone or use a mobile emulator.

[Docs on integration](https://paddle.com/docs/paddlejs-setup).

Do you think I'm loading the script incorrectly or is it a payment system flaw (which I doubt as they have too many clients not to have noticed this already).

Code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Paddle.Setup({
    vendor: 20000,
    debug: true
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 94 in the Paddle script is this switch statement:

```
switch(os){
  case'Mac OS X':
    osVersion=/Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
    break;
  case'Android':
    osVersion=/Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
    break;
  case'iOS':
    osVersion=/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
    osVersion=osVersion[1]+'.'+ osVersion[2]+'.'+(osVersion[3]|0);
    break;
}
```

It seems to be trying to determine the version of the operating system for Android, iOS and Mac OS X devices.

The variable `nAgt` is the browser's user agent string (taken from `navigator.userAgent`). These regular expressions assume that if the user agent header contains the string 'Mac OS X', 'Android' or 'OS', then it'll be immediately followed by a version number.

If any of these regex matches fail then `exec` will return null and `null[1]` will throw the TypeError you're seeing.

What phone or emulator are you using? Can you put this in a JS Fiddle on the device and see what it says?

`document.body.innerHTML = "<p>" + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";`

I would imagine you'll have a string that satisfies one of the switch conditions above but doesn't return a regex match.

This is just the result of badly written code from Paddle, which should not be expecting User Agent strings to be in a specific format as they can be overridden by all sorts of things (users, plugins, devices, proxies etc).

If you can override the user agent for the device or emulator you're using so it matches one of the regex patterns, do that and you'll no longer get the error.

Comment: thank you for clearing things up. Sometimes when working with big apis, the last thing you expect is them using bad practices, blaming yourself instead.